# Select from current cell to end of row (a la SHIFT + END)

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

When I have a cell selected, how can I select from that cell to the end of its row? <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>END</kbd> works in most spreadsheet programs, but I can't get it to work in Google Sheets. I use Chrome on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- try: <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`SHIFT`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`RIGHT ARROW`**</kbd>
- for Mac keyboards it would be: <kbd>**`COMMAND`**⌘</kbd> + <kbd>**`SHIFT`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`RIGHT ARROW`**</kbd>
- and same applies for the rest of the directions